# Remove metadata from json results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, metadata

I'm using ActiveResource to establish a REST connection with rails 4.2 to an ADS Advantage server using the WebPlatform from ADS. It returns json with "__metadata". How can I remove the "__metadata"?

{
         "__metadata": {
           "uri": "http://.....",
           "key_fields": "ID",
           "rows_affected": 0,
           "last_autoinc": 0
 },
In my class I have added self.include_format_in_path = false, to remove the .json from the end of the uri.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this in the following steps:

parse the JSON:

```
parsed_json = JSON.parse('{ "__metadata": { "uri": "http://.....", "key_fields": "ID", "rows_affected": 0, "last_autoinc": 0 }}')
```

then you will get a hash type and you just need to get the inside of `__metadata`:

```
result = parsed_json['__metadata']
```

then you can just return it or print it:

```
puts result.to_json
#=> {"uri"=>"http://.....", "key_fields"=>"ID", "rows_affected"=>0, "last_autoinc"=>0}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer is right but my question was not right. I was not able to return a Json and rails was erroring. I had to create a module and overwrite the decode method in the ActiveResource::Formats::JsonFormat so that rails was getting from ADS server an array of hashes.